# Serial IO Port Communication Powershell ESC Series

Tags: powershell, serial-port

$port object (Serial.IO.Port) is created for UPS communication and sending right keystrokes(carriage return & new line feed) with 
$port.write("`r") or  $port.write("`n") also receiving data from serial port using $port.ReadExisting()

Can any body help me to send {ESC} through $port.write method like $port.write("`e")

I tested many one but its not working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried passing ESC as byte (0x1B)?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution to send `ESC` to console. to do that use one variable and store ASCII value of **ESC** and send this with `WriteLine()` method

```
$var = [char]27
$port.NewLine = "`r"
$port.writeline($var)
```